# Remove multiple lines that satisfy a condition

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table below:

| UPC | Article_# | MS_BC | MS_PRA | MS_ON | MS_QUE | MS_ATL |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 123 | A123 | A | B | A | B | A |
| 124 | A123 | A | A | B | B | B |
| 125 | A124 | C | A | B | B | B |
| 126 | A124 | A | A | B | B | B |

I want to keep rows of Article_# if all of the MS values are in A or B only. If any of the rows contain C then I need to remove all rows for the same Article_#. In example below, because MS_BC = 'C' for Article# 124, the entire article_# (2 rows) must be removed. This is what I need to see:

| UPC | Article_# | MS_BC | MS_PRA | MS_ON | MS_QUE | MS_ATL |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 123 | A123 | A | B | A | B | A |
| 124 | A123 | A | A | B | B | B |

How do I do that?

Comment: **exlude** them from the output of a query, or **delete** them from the table?

Comment: I can exclude one line (i.e. row 3) using the MS_BC = 'C' but I don't know how to exclude line 4

Comment: Please provide the SQL you have tried so we can assist you better

Comment: While asking a question, you need to provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example):
(1) DDL and sample data population, i.e. CREATE table(s) plus INSERT T-SQL statements. 
(2) What you need to do, i.e. logic and your code attempt implementation of it in T-SQL. 
(3) Desired output, based on the sample data in the #1 above.
(4) Your SQL Server version (SELECT @@version;).

Comment: You didn't answer the question, but it sounds like you mean exclude from the query results

Comment: Please clarify what you mean by  "Remove multiple lines" since that could mean exclude them from a SELECT query, a view, delete them from a table or perhaps even something more like "not insert into a temp table" or some such

Comment: I need to exclude entries from the output of the query, I'm querying a table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your table has many rows then using LIKE as suggested in other answers will be slow.

Something like this should perform well:

```
SELECT *
FROM table_name
WHERE Article_# IN (
    SELECT Article_#
    FROM table_name
    WHERE 
        MS_BC     NOT IN ('A', 'B')
        OR MS_PRA NOT IN ('A', 'B')
        OR MS_ON  NOT IN ('A', 'B')
        OR MS_QUE NOT IN ('A', 'B')
        OR MS_ATL NOT IN ('A', 'B')
);
```

Answer (score 2):

One more way to handle it.

**SQL**

```
-- DDL and sample data population, start
DECLARE @tbl TABLE (UPC INT PRIMARY KEY, Article_# VARCHAR(10), MS_BC CHAR(1),MS_PRA CHAR(1), MS_ON CHAR(1), MS_QUE CHAR(1), MS_ATL CHAR(1));
INSERT INTO @tbl (UPC, Article_#, MS_BC, MS_PRA, MS_ON, MS_QUE, MS_ATL) VALUES
('123', 'A123', 'A', 'B', 'A', 'B', 'A'),
('124', 'A123', 'A', 'A', 'B', 'B', 'B'),
('125', 'A124', 'C', 'A', 'B', 'B', 'B'),
('126', 'A124', 'A', 'A', 'B', 'B', 'B');
-- DDL and sample data population, end

;WITH rs AS
(
    SELECT Article_# 
    FROM @tbl
    CROSS APPLY (VALUES 
        (MS_BC), (MS_PRA), (MS_ON), 
        (MS_QUE), (MS_ATL)) AS t(c)
    WHERE c NOT IN ('A', 'B')
)
SELECT * 
FROM @tbl
WHERE  Article_# NOT IN (SELECT Article_# FROM rs);
```

**Output**

```
+-----+-----------+-------+--------+-------+--------+--------+
| UPC | Article_# | MS_BC | MS_PRA | MS_ON | MS_QUE | MS_ATL |
+-----+-----------+-------+--------+-------+--------+--------+
| 123 | A123      | A     | B      | A     | B      | A      |
| 124 | A123      | A     | A      | B     | B      | B      |
+-----+-----------+-------+--------+-------+--------+--------+
```

Answer (score 1):

Equality is symmetrical in nature, so you could do

```
select * 
from t
where article_# not in (select article_# 
                        from t 
                        where 'C' in (ms_bc, ms_pra, ms_on, ms_que, ms_atl));
```

Be careful with `not in` though, if you have `nulls`

Answer (score 0):

Here is one way, using `LIKE` and a concatenation trick:

```sql
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT *, COUNT(CASE WHEN MS_BC + MS_PRA + MS_ON + MS_QUE + MS_ATL
                              LIKE '%C%' THEN 1 END)
                  OVER (PARTITION BY [Article_#]) AS cnt
    FROM yourTable
)

SELECT UPC, [Article_#], MS_BC, MS_PRA, MS_ON, MS_QUE, MS_ATL
FROM cte
WHERE cnt = 0;
```

We form a string of 5 characters from the `MS` columns and then check that a `C` character be present for any given article.

Comment: The OP's data has some problem.  According to the rules given, row 4 should be retained.

Comment: What if some values are NULLs?

Comment: UPC 126 belongs to A124 which according to the rules should be excluded because UPC 125 is excluded.

Comment: On a cellphone at the moment.

Answer (score 0):

I'd go with using not exists:

```
select
*
from
table1 t
where not exists (select article from table1 where ms_bc = 'C' and t.article = table1.article)
```

[Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/ae7775/6)